# Passing blocks into nested method within class_eval in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eval

I want to be able to define a block, and later evaluate that block from within a dynamically generated module/class.  It seems like I could accomplish this somehow using `eval` and `block.binding`, but I haven't figured it out.

I have this as the base:

```
def define_module(name, &block)
  name = name.to_s.gsub(/\/(.?)/) { "::#{$1.upcase}" }.gsub(/(?:^|_)(.)/) { $1.upcase }
  parts = name.split("::")
  parts.each_with_index do |part, index|
    sub_name = parts[0..index].join("::")
    eval("module #{sub_name}; end")
  end
  clazz = eval(name)
  clazz.class_eval(&block) if block_given?
  clazz
end

def add_module(name, &block)
  module_block = block
  define_module(name).class_eval <<-EOF
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        # something like this, I'm stuck
        instance_eval(&#{module_block})
      end
    end
  EOF
end
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
add_module("My::Library") do
  def a_method
    "added 'a_method'"
  end
end

class ::User
  include My::Library
end

user = ::User.new

assert_equal "added 'a_method'", user.a_method
```

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: ok, don't use string based evals, use block based evals, that way you can close over `block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
def add_module(name, &block)
    define_module(name).class_eval do
        class << self; self; end.send(:define_method, :included) { |base|
            base.class_eval(&block)
        }
    end
end

add_module("My::Library") do
    def a_method
        "added 'a_method'"
    end
end

class ::User
    include My::Library
end

user = ::User.new
user.a_method #=> "added a_method"
```

**EDIT:**

Why don't you just do this instead? Much simpler, and it's actually the *job* of a module:

```
def add_module(name, &block)
    define_module(name).class_eval(&block)
end
```

Comment: though the whole idea seems weird -- why not just `class_eval` the block on the module itself rather than waiting until the `include` ? Seems like you're unnecessarily rewriting the entire idea of a module using the `included` hook???